# dB calculator? VBA function writing

Tags: vba, excel, decibel

So I've got quite the specific task. I want to create a function that will add decibel units together. Currently, you have to input something like

`=10*LOG10(10^(A1/10)+10^(A2/10))`

and make this even longer if you have like 15 parts you want to add together. Kind of a pain.

Ideally, it would work like the excel function `SUM` and just take in any input. Can someone help me put this together, or at least show me what SUM would look like if you had to create it from scratch?

Best,
T. Heng

Comment: End code ended up being:
    Function DBADD3(ParamArray nums()) As Double
    Dim DBPrTot As Variant

    DBPrTot = 0

    For i = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
        DBPrTot = DBPrTot + 10 ^ (nums(i) / 10)
        
    Next i

    DBADD3 = 10 * WorksheetFunction.Log10(DBPrTot)
    
End Function

Answer (score 5):

This little *UDF()* will give you more flexibility:

```
Public Function decibelle(rng As Range, N As Long) As Double
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, i As Long, Z As Double
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = 1 To N
        Z = Z + 10 ^ (rng(i) / 10)
    Next i
    decibelle = 10 * wf.Log10(Z)
End Function
```

where the first argument is the range of inputs and the second argument is the number of inputs:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

and if you want the *UDF()* to be more like *SUM()* consider:

```
Public Function decibelle2(rng As Range) As Double
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, r As Range, Z As Double
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    For Each r In rng
        Z = Z + 10 ^ (r.Value / 10)
    Next r
    decibelle2 = 10 * wf.Log10(Z)
End Function
```

so you could use it like:

```
=decibelle2(A1:A2)
```

Comment: Oh this is nifty and works well! What if I wanted to choose parameters that were not successive? Like A1:A2, A4, A6 and so forth? Such as with ParamArray below?

Comment: @T.Heng I agree that `ParamArray` would be a BIG improvement to this code.................sadly, I am not an expert of `ParamArray`'s use...........I suggest that once you are satisfied with a version of the *UDF()*, open a new question on the `ParamArray` issue.

Answer (score 1):

The below is a very simple example of a `User Defined Function` (which should be typed into a standard module) that can take any number of parameters and return the sum of these parameters. Your example seems to involve more advanced logic, so you will have to expand upon my example. Let us know if you need more assistance.

```
Function AddSomeDigits(ParamArray nums()) As Double
    Dim vRunningTotal As Variant

    vRunningTotal = 0

    For i = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
        vRunningTotal = vRunningTotal + nums(i)
    Next i

    AddSomeDigits = vRunningTotal
End Function
```

Comment: I like using *ParamArray* ...............you could make something REALLY close to *SUM()* using it.

Comment: Very good example! This is pretty much like SUM. If I have to factor in the equation, I want the part that's going into the LOG10 function to be using those inputs. I'm having trouble with using those iterations. Can you assist me? Is it clear what I'm asking based off of my original post?

Function DBADD3(ParamArray nums()) As Double
    Dim DBPrTot As Variant

    DBPrTot = 0

    For i = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
        DBPrTot = DBPrTot + 10 ^ (nums(i) / 10)
        
    Next i

    DBADD3 = 10 * wf.Log10(DBPrTot)
    
End Function
Is what I have now

Comment: 'code'Function DBADD3(ParamArray nums()) As Double
    Dim DBPrTot As Variant

    DBPrTot = 0

    For i = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
        DBPrTot = DBPrTot + 10 ^ (nums(i) / 10)
        
    Next i

    DBADD3 = 10 * wf.Log10(DBPrTot)
    
End Function

Comment: @T.Heng Good to hear that you figured it out. Basically, `nums` works like any other array, where you'd reference each value using its indexer. For example, the first value would be `nums(1)`, etc.